# Include Railtie initialization in seeds.rb in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a simple railtie, adding a bunch of stuff to ActiveRecord:

```
  0 module Searchable
  1   class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
  2     initializer 'searchable.model_additions' do
  3       ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
  4         extend ModelAdditions
  5       end
  6     end
  7   end
  8 end
```

I require this file (in /lib) by adding the following line to config/environment.rb before the application is called:

```
require 'searchable'
```

This works great with my application and there are no major problems.

I have however encountered a problem with rake db:seed.

In my seeds.rb file, I read data in from a csv and populate the database.  The problem I am having is that the additions I made to ActiveRecord don't get loaded, and seeds fails with a method_missing error.  I am not calling these methods, but I assume that since seeds.rb loads the models, it tries to call some of the methods and that's why it fails.

Can anyone tell me a better place to put the require so that it will be included every time ActiveRecord is loaded (not just when the full application is loaded)?  I would prefer to keep the code outside of my models, as it is code shared between most of my models and I want to keep them clean and DRY.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the extend there just adds it to ActiveRecord::Base.

When a model class is referenced, via Rails 3.1 autoloading/constant lookup, it will load the class. At that point, it is pure Ruby (nothing magic) as to what happens, basically. So I think you have at least a few options. The "bad" option that kind of does what you want it to hook into dependency loading. Maybe something like:

```
module ActiveSupport
  module Dependencies
    alias_method(:load_missing_constant_renamed_my_app_name_here, :load_missing_constant)
    undef_method(:load_missing_constant)
    def load_missing_constant(from_mod, const_name)
       # your include here if const_name = 'ModelName'
       # perhaps you could list the app/models directory, put that in an Array, and do some_array.include?(const_name)
       load_missing_constant_renamed_my_app_name_here(from_mod, const_name)
    end
  end
end
```

Another way to do it would be to use a Railtie like you were doing and add a class method to ActiveRecord::Base that then includes stuff, like:

```
module MyModule
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "my_name.active_record" do
      ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
        # ActiveRecord::Base gets new behavior
        include ::MyModule::Something # where you add behavior. consider using an ActiveSupport::Concern
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If using an ActiveSupport::Concern:

```
module MyModule
  module Something
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      # this area is basically for anything other than class and instance methods
      # add class_attribute's, etc.
    end

    module ClassMethods
      # class method definitions go here

      def include_some_goodness_in_the_model
        # include or extend a module
      end 
    end

    # instance method definitions go here
  end
end
```

Then in each model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  include_some_goodness_in_the_model

  #...

end
```

However, that isn't much better than just doing an include in each model, which is what I'd recommend.